# Sonarqube S2583 reported as Blocker issue in SonarJava 4.15.0.12310 + Sonarqube 5.6.4

Tags: sonarqube

While S2583 is defined as a Major issue, is reported as a Blocker issue, any idea that it can explain this? This code portion is detected as a Blocker instead of a major issue. Thanks in advance

```
private final List<Object> lstError = new ArrayList<>(); // 1: Implies 'lstError' is not null...

// ... more code ...

public List<Object> getLstError() {
  return this.lstError != null ? lstError : null; //2: Expression is always true.
}
```

[Reported issue vs defined rule image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h99WR.png)

Comment: Read [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/private-and-final-methods-in-java/). Why do you think that "this.lstError != null" is not always true?

Comment: That's not the problem. Sentence is always true. The problem is in Sonarqube, report issue as blocker when really it's a major one. I suppose was a bug in the java code analyzer, and i updated it from 4.4.xxx to 4.15.xxx, but continues detecting wrongly this issue. See the image link. Could my Sonarqube instance be buggy?

Answer (score 2):

Each issue is reported at the severity the rule holds in the relevant quality profile *at the time the issue is raised*. Once an issue is raised, it isn't changed by analysis even if you change the severity of the rule. So for instance if I:

- add rule A as Blocker in my profile and issue i1 is raised

  - i1 is a Blocker issue
- update rule A to Critical and issue i2 is raised

  - i2 is a Critical issue.
  - i1 is still a Blocker
- update rule A to Major and issue i3 is raised

  - i3 is a Major issue.
  - i2 is still a Critical
  - i1 is still a Blocker

And so on...

Note that you can manually update the severities of existing issues (assuming you have the right privileges on the project).

Comment: Ok, thank you. That explains many things. Actual quality profiles are migrated from older instances of Sonarqube as database too, so issues can be raised on any time as blocker and later in other projects as major if an profile were updated.  So when an instance of Sonarqube is updated to another version, may occur that a project were previously analyzed with a distinct profile.